# Exporting a DOORS Module with batch and dxl?

Tags: batch-file, ibm-doors

I have a dxl script which exports an open module as a XML-file to a given path. Now I would like to run this script within a batch-file, so that it can be automated.

the problem is: using the -batch command in the batch-file, the module is not opening, and thus the script is not working.

So I thought to open the module in doors execute the export and close DOORS again. But I can't figure out, how to open the module directly.

I tried with:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe" -dxl C:\Users\bal2LR\Desktop\DOORSScript\Doors2xml.dxl -project /Project/SW/SRS/SST -user Manu -password test
```

the module is called SST. I get the Error, the project SST was not found... Of course not, because it's not a project, it's a module.

Somebody knows how to do it? Maybe only open the project, open in the script the module and at the end of the script I close everything again? Do you know the commands? Or is there a better way? the perfect result would be that it works in batch-mode...

Comment: Post the portion of the DXL script that is opening the module. Remember that in batch mode there is no GUI loaded, so if you try to open the module visibly it will probably fail.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it already out how to do it. I've added the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself with the help of the DOORS Support.

for everybody who has the same problem:
you can open the module and the view in the beginning of the script:

```
Module mod= read("/Projekte/test/SW/SRS/SST",false)
View v= view("SST_Complete")
bool test 
test = load(mod,v)
```

That's all. Additionally you can pass variables with the -cli command in the command prompt to change the module or view. This is also working in Batch-Mode =)